# Get selectbox expand/user focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a select box element in my form. When clicked, I want to generate the options to display and insert the html code.

I have tried placing alerts on `onclick`, `onfocus`, `onshow` events, but nothing happens :/

The html:

```
<select name="select-building" id="select-building"  data-native-menu="false"  onfocus="populateBuildingOptions();">  </select>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function populateBuildingOptions(){ b = "{{\"buildingCode\":\"1\",\"buildingName\":\asca"\"},{\"buildingCode\":\"2\",\"buildingName\":\"vsdvs\"}}";

 buildingOptions = jQuery.parseJSON(b);
$("#select-building").empty();

for(var i=0;i<buildingOptions.length;i++){
 $("#select-building").append("<option
value=\""+buildingOptions.get(i).buildingCode+"\">"+buildingOptions.buildingName+"/option>"   );
} }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you're working with, the HTML and JavaScript? Possible a simple demo to show us your problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: The select is empty to begin with? but when I click it to select an option it generates a list of options and populates it?

Comment: [Your idea works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/uTJzV/), so there must be something wrong with your code; show us what you have.

Comment: thanx Daedalus for confirming, and for the example. I just noticed my json is invalid, but thats beside the point. I'll figure it out and post what went wrong

Comment: As far as I understand it, you aren't supposed to have spaces between your tag brackets and the tag content, eg..  `< a` = incorrect, `<a` =  correct.  Not to mention your select tag has no ending tag.

Comment: I put the space in there because it wouldn't show the html otherwise, html is valid in my code. Thanx for your example above! wasn't used to working with jsfiddle before, will definitely use it from now on

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTJzV/4/ thanks to the help in the comments